# SSMS - What is the max string size that can be displayed in the grid for VARCHAR(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What is the max string size that can be displayed in the grid for VARCHAR(MAX)?
I've gotten 2 MB.  Does this go larger?

[image]

Comment: The 2097152 characters clearly indicated on the screenshot isn't the answer your want..?

Comment: Curious how far it can go.  Would have also have liked to have been able to search and find the answer.

Comment: Simply putting a too large number tells you the answer; it reduces it back down to 2097152. SSMS is an IDE, not a presentation layer. If you need more characters than than, you should be using something other than an IDE.

Comment: If that's the actual number, I'm just really lucky.  I just put in 2^21 and I guess that's the number.
This is the easiest way to get data out of SQL in an Ad Hoc fashion.  I just need a sample to put in a Queue for testing in this case.